# How can I horizontally align the dashboard item at the navigation section with the items in the header section

Tags: html, css

im trying to figure how to align the next items: [what im trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j52Jd.png)
and this is what im expected to do: [how it is supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYG8c.png)

here is the repo: https://github.com/yamildev/project-admin-dashboard
and here is the code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" /> 
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
</head>

    

    <body>    
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div id="header-container"> <!-- here are the items from left --->
                <div id="header">
                    <div class=" search-container">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">search</span>
                        <input type="search" value="busqueda: ...">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">notifications</span> 
                        <img src="/profile-icons/man.svg" alt="">
  
                        campana icono nombre
                    </div>
                    <div>icono texto</div>
                    <div>new upload share</div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li class="dashboard-item header" /* this is the item that im trying to align with the others*/
id="dashboard-header">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined" style="font-size:3rem">dashboard</span>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item home">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">home</span>
                        <p>Home</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item profile">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">person</span>
                        <p>Profile</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item message">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">mail</span>
                        <p>Messages</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item history">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">schedule</span>
                        <p>History</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item tasks">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">description</span>
                        <p>Tasks</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item communities">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">groups</span>
                        <p>Groups</p>   
                    </li> 
                    <li class="dashboard-item settings settings">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined" >settings</span>
                        <p>Settings</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item support">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">question_mark</span>
                        <p>Support</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dashboard-item privacy">
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">verified_user</span>
                        <p>Privacy</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                
            </div>
            <div id="main-container">
                <div id="main-left">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h4>Super cool Project</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim minima maiores, doloremque atque porro delectus! Saepe, exercitationem debitis corporis molestiae molestias deserunt aperiam quas alias, illo enim, quis ex explicabo.                            
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <h4>Less cool project</h4>
                        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste cupiditate, et officia voluptatem placeat quae nihil natus assumenda voluptate laborum, perspiciatis voluptas veritatis laudantium odio porro id illo cumque aspernatur.</p>
                        
                    </div>
                        <div class="box">
                        <h4>Impossible App</h4>
                        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste cupiditate, et officia voluptatem placeat quae nihil natus assumenda voluptate laborum, perspiciatis voluptas veritatis laudantium odio porro id illo cumque aspernatur.</p>
                        <div>icon icon icon</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <h4>Easy Peasy App</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim illo perspiciatis nihil amet veritatis a fuga aliquid culpa! Natus id non voluptatibus voluptate debitis sit incidunt ab consequuntur porro odit.</p>
                        <div>icon icon icon</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">b
                        <h4>Ad Blocker</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Dolorum consequuntur architecto commodi. Adipisci, facere quis? Laboriosam dolore numquam iste adipisci suscipit culpa, consequatur iure, eaque earum praesentium nesciunt nostrum aperiam!</p>
                        <div>icon icon icon</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <h4>Money Maker</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis exercitationem neque architecto, enim ratione veritatis. Sapiente nemo, voluptate expedita tenetur consectetur vitae ut aspernatur exercitationem distinctio voluptatem modi unde doloribus!</p>
                        <div>icon icon icon</div>
                    </div>
                
                
            </div>
            <div id="aside">
                <div>announcements
                    <div>
                        <p>Site Maintenance</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                    </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Community share day</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam odit animi</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Update privacy policy</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>trendings
                    <div>img usr subtext
                    </div>
                    <div>img usr subtext
                    </div>
                    <div>img usr subtext
                    </div>
                    <div>img usr subtext
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

:root {
    font-size: 16px;
}
#header img{
    width: 50px;
}
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 1px solid red;

}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template: 3fr 10fr / 0.8fr 4.5fr;
}
 
#header-container {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / -1;
}
#header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
}
#header > .search-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#header > .search-container > input {
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: none;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #e2e8f0;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 90%;
}
/*header outline*/
#header > *{
}
#main-container {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / -1 / -1;

    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template: 1fr / 2.5fr 1fr;
} 
#main-left{
    display: grid;

}
#dashboard-header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#header-container,
#navigation {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#navigation {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #e5f2fa;
    background-color: #1992d4;
    display: grid;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / -1 / 2;  
}
#navigation > ul {
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#navigation .dashboard-item span {
    width: 3rem;
}
#navigation .dashboard-item  {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
#navigation > ul > li {
   list-style-type: none; 
}

#navigation > ul {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;

}
.communities{
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}

#main-left {

    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px,1fr));
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

}



#aside {
    display: grid;

    grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr;
}
```

Im trying to figure out how to horizontally align this items.
https://github.com/yamildev/project-admin-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra row at the top of your main layout grid. Place the dashboard icon and text in this row, along with the search bar and everything else which sits beside it. You should then be able to set the vertical alignment of all elements in that row to the centre.

[image: illustration of suggested grid layout]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto auto auto / 160px auto;
}
.main-grid>* {
  padding: 1em;
}
.logo, nav {
  background: #4590ce;
  color: white;
}
.logo, .header1 {
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}
.logo img {
  display: block;
  width: 1.5em;
}
.header1 {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.header1 input {
  border: 0;
  background: #e3e8ef;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
nav {
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
main {
  background-color: #e3e8ef;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(112,115,119,0.2) 0%, rgba(227,232,239,0.2) 100%);
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-grid">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77123699.svg">
    Dashboard
  </div>
  <header class="header1"><input type="search"> Morgan Oakley</header>
  <nav>
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>Profile</a>
    <a>Message</a>
    <a>History</a>
    <a>Tasks</a>
    <a>Communities</a>
  </nav>
  <header class="header2">Hi there, Morgan Oakley (@morgan)</header>
  <main>
    Main area
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </main>
</div>
```